# Find the second derivative of $H(x) = \int_{-x}^{x}[f(t)+f(-t)]dt$

Tags: real-analysis

I am not sure how to deal with a function being in both bounds. Can we just plug them in as if they are any other a and b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \int_{-x}^x = \int_{-x}^0 + \int_0^x = \int_0^x - \int_0^{-x} $$

$$
\frac d{dx} \int_{-x}^x g(t)\,dt = \frac d{dx} \int_0^x g(t)\,dt - \frac d {dx} \int_0^{-x} g(t)\,dt = g(x) - g(-x)\cdot\frac d {dx}(-x)=\cdots.
$$

Comment: what if $f$ is not continuous on 0? in this case we shouldn't split the integral that way

Comment: @OussamaBoussif Unrelated.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $f(t)+f(-t)$ is an even function. So

$H(x) = \int_{-x}^{x}[f(t)+f(-t)]dt 
      = 2\int_{0}^{x}[f(t)+f(-t)]dt$

So $H'(x) = 2f(x)+2f(-x)$

$H''(x) = 2f'(x)-2f'(-x)$

Comment: What is an "even" function? Does that mean it is symmetric about 0?

Comment: Symmetric about the $y$ axis: $f(x)=f(-x)$.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to have $x$ in both endpoints, just split the integral:

$$
\int_{-x}^x f(t) dt = \int_{-x}^a f(t)dt + \int_a^x f(t)dt = -\int_a^{-x} f(t)dt + \int_a^x f(t)dt.
$$

Edit: don't forget the chain rule:

$$
\dfrac{d}{dx} \int_a^{h(x)} f(t)dt = f(h(x))h'(x)
$$

Comment: I believe something like this is necessary however using those bounds the answer I get is still 0. Can someone please work it out after splitting the integral.

Comment: Don't forget the chain rule. See my edit.

Comment: Ok thank you, now I see where the issue is.